# issues with closing a window in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

To keep this as short as possible - In my program I start with Page1 and when I press a button I want to open Page2 and close Page1, I have managed to open Page2 but I cant close Page1, I have tried using `.destroy()` but it closes everything not just the page. I looked around some questions here on SO but couldn't find much in the same layout as my code so I wasnt sure how to apply it to mine. This is my first `tkinter` project so I am still getting to grips with it.

My code is;

```
class Page1:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        #lots of labels and buttons
        self.BTNNextPage = ttk.Button(master, text = "Proceed",
                                  command = self.NextPage)
        self.BTNNextPage.place(x=450, y=420)

    def NextPage(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Page2(self.newWindow)
        self.master.destroy()

class Page2():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        #tried Page1.destroy() here but Page1 has no attibute destroy
        #more labels and buttons

def main():
    widthpixels=690
    heightpixels=500
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.configure(background='black')
    root.iconbitmap("Image")
    root.wm_title("Title")
    root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(widthpixels, heightpixels))
    app = Page1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you destroy `root`, it destroys all the widgets contained, including `Page2`. To destroy only page 1, one possibility is to make the page classes inherit from `tk.Frame`, so that they have a `destroy` method:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True) # display page 1
        #lots of labels and buttons:
        tk.Label(self, text='Page 1').place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
        self.BTNNextPage = ttk.Button(self, text="Proceed", command=self.NextPage)
        self.BTNNextPage.place(x=450, y=420)

    def NextPage(self):
        self.app = Page2(self.master) # create page 2
        self.destroy() # remove page 1

class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True) # display page 2
        # create widgets on page 2
        tk.Label(self, text='Page 2').pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.master.destroy).pack(side='bottom')

def main():
    widthpixels=690
    heightpixels=500
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.configure(background='black')
    root.wm_title("Title")
    root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(widthpixels, heightpixels))
    app = Page1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but page1 doesnt get deleted, page2 is just overlayed onto it

Comment: `self.destroy()` in `NextPage` does destroy page1, so page2 is not just overlayed onto it.

Comment: when i run this the contents of page1 and page2 just appear together in the same window when i hit the next button

Comment: I don't understand why, I tried it on my computer and it worked: Page1 appeared, then when I clicked 'Proceed', Page1 disappeared and Page2 replaced it. Try to put  `self.destroy()` before `Page2(self.master)` in `NextPage`.

Comment: its still the same

Comment: Do you run the code as is or have you added the stuff you haven't posted in the question?

Comment: i ran the code as is but just with my other labels and buttons, ive established that for some reason my page2 is taking everything from page1 and sticking it on there too

Comment: When you create your other widgets, have you replaced `master` by `self` so that they belong to page2 frame and not to `root` (see how I created the buttons and labels)?

Comment: page2 has a `self.master = master`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134773/discussion-between-j-4321-and-badnamehere).